# protocol buffers, What is in serialized data?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protocol-buffers-3

I am new to protocol buffers, and really want to know more about it, so sorry for noob question.

What is in serialized data, only values or both keys and values? I think there is only values, and if someone wants to deserialize it, he/she must has scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's both key & value:

> As you know, a protocol buffer message is a series of key-value pairs.
>   The binary version of a message just uses the field's number as the
>   key – the name and declared type for each field can only be determined
>   on the decoding end by referencing the message type's definition (i.e.
>   the .proto file).
>   https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

For eg, say you have a proto file as:

```
$  cat my.proto 
message header {
  required uint32 u1 = 1;
  required uint32 u2 = 2;
  optional uint32 u3 = 3 [default=0];
  optional bool   b1 = 4 [default=true];
  optional string s1 = 5;
  optional uint32 u4 = 6;
  optional uint32 u5 = 7;
  optional string s2 = 9;
  optional string s3   = 10; 
  optional uint32 u6 = 8;
}
```

Dump out encoded data from memory:

```
(gdb) x/10xb 0x7fd70db7e964
0x7fd70db7e964: 0x08    0xff    0xff    0x01    0x10    0x08    0x40    0xf7
0x7fd70db7e96c: 0xd4    0x38
```

Decode:

```
$ echo 08ffff01100840f7d438 | xxd -r -p | protoc --decode_raw
1: 32767
2: 8
8: 928375
```

1,2,8 are keys

from proto file above:

```
1 => u1, 
2 => u2,
8 => u6
```

So, it becomes:

```
u1: 32767
u2: 8
u6: 928375
```

I used data from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049657/how-to-decode-binary-raw-google-protobuf-data):

Comment: purely as a convenience - this can be a useful tool alongside protoc (especially if you're debugging, as it explains each byte): https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode?hex=08FFFF01100840F7D438

Answer (score 2):

This depends a little on whether you use the binary form (which is typically the default when dealing with protobuf), or the json form (yes, protobuf includes a json option, at least in some libraries - not all).

In the binary form, the data consists of the field *numbers*, and the values; not the field *names*. As an example, if we use the example of:

```
optional string name = 1; // remove the "optional" if using proto3 syntax
```

and assign a value of "Nika" (and serialize it), then the binary data will include the `1` (in a slightly tweaked form), and the UTF-8 encoded form of `Nika`, but it will *not* contain "name".

You don't *absolutely need* to have the schema to decode it, but it will make things a **lot** easier if you do, as many parts of the specification are otherwise ambiguous, using the same "wire type" (i.e. the encoding format) for multiple data types, or for multiple *meanings* of the same data type (for example: you can't tell whether an integer is signed, unsigned, or "zig zag encoded" without the schema (or a good guess), and the actual value that you get can vary hugely based on this.

To see what you *can* grok from raw protobuf data without the schema, try: https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode